# Assigning value to checkbox?

Tags: jquery

Ok thanks to the guys on here we have sorted functions for checkbox click, and are now using unobtrusive js.

What I want to achieve is..

We have a form, and on submit with checkbox unclicked, the form submits as it would normally...

But.. I have added an option to click checkbox, and display hidden content .. which I want to be part of same form, but with additional values etc..

Essentially...

if checkbox is unchecked, show standard submit button.

if checkbox is clicked, hide standard button and toggle additional form elements and new submit button.

The issue I am facing is :

1. passing a numeric value onclick from the checkbox, so need set to 1 or 0 
   0 being standard do nothing
   1 hiding submit button, and toggling hidden additional form fields.

I can get the toggle working, but onclick of the checkbox it doesnt do anything.

I am also baffled as to hide the submit button ( normally displayed ) if checkbox is clicked.

script for hidden element:

```
$('.styledCheckbox').change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "0") {
    $('.extraForm').show('fast');
    }else if ($(this).val() == "0") {
    $('.extraForm').hide('fast');
}
```

});

script for the checkbox:

```
 $(function(){
  $('.styledCheckbox').click(function(){
    setCheckboxDisplay(this);
  });
});
```

html for the checkbox:

```
<input name="include" type="checkbox" id="checkbox"  class="styledCheckbox" />
```

hidden div

```
<div class="extraForm" style="display:none;">
                                        <!--extra form elements and submit button here-->
                                    </div>
```

Oh and would idealy like form to have dynamic action based on event handler, so if standard form submit.. do something, if checkbox selected , form submit ... do something else

Also looking to change form action based on CHECKBOX selection ?

so something like ...

changeAction(url) {
    document.this_form.action = "clicked.php";
}

< form method="POST" name="this_form" action="unclicked.php">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not working because you don't have a value set for your checkbox. Also, it is better to the jQuery `is(":checked")` function to check if the checkbox is checked:

**JS:**

```
$('.styledCheckbox').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('.extraForm').show('fast');
    } else {
        $('.extraForm').hide('fast');
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input name="include" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="yes" class="styledCheckbox" />
```

Ad@m

Comment: Ok great that works. Is it possible to  change the form action ? any suggestions .. thanks

Comment: You could also simply check `if (this.checked) {`... the performance would be better. No need to wrap jQuery around the object just to find out whether it's checked or not.

Comment: Would it be like: see amended question

Comment: You can change the form action with `jQuery('#formid').attr('action', '/new/action/here')` (replace formid with the ID of the form)

Comment: I am struggling on the change form action part..because I need my checkbox to change the formaction url...
My checkbox code is in question. value for checkbox ="yes" so not sure where to go now? any suggestions, I dont get your jQuery code Mark

Comment: To change the form's action, simply place `$("#this_form").attr("action","/path/to/other/submit.php");` where appropriate. In your situation, you would need to place it under the `$(".extraForm")` lines in the code I posted above. Ad@m

Comment: Also, I will explain how the code works: first it checks if the checkbox has the `:checked` filter, meaning that it is checked, and if it is, show the extra part of the form, otherwise, hide it. Ad@m

Comment: Thanks Adam :) I maybe getting the hang of this.. but dont speak to soon he says lol. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to toggle the form based on the checked status if the checkbox.
If that's the case try:

```
$('.styledCheckbox').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('.extraForm').show('fast');
    } else {
      $('.extraForm').hide('fast');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks looks like Great Minds think Alike